# How do I write a recursive function to print a string in reverse in C?

Tags: c, recursion, reverse, c-strings, function-definition

I need any given string to be printed in reverse using recursion. I have tried changing the function prototype and definition by changing the return value type and parameter list of the function stringReverse. stdout of this does not print anything for the reverse string and I cannot figure out why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 100
char stringReverse(void);
size_t i;
unsigned int pass;
int hold;
char a1[SIZE]; 
char a2[SIZE]; 
int main(void) {
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
        a1[i] = 0;
    }
    
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf_s("%[^\n]99s", a1);

    printf("%s%s\n\n", "string is:\n", a1);
    
stringReverse();
}

char stringReverse(void)
{
    for (pass = 1; pass < SIZE; ++pass) {
        if (a1[i] < a1[i + 1]) {
            hold = a1[i];
            a1[i] = a1[i + 1];
            a1[i + 1] = hold;
        }
    }
    printf("%s%s", "reverse is:\n", a2);
}
```

Comment: What you've written is not a recursive function in the first place. Also, recursion would be a massive overkill for this job. You can instead, simply use a reverse for loop or `strrev`

Comment: The reverse of a 0-char string is itself; the reverse of a n-char string is the reverse of the (n-1)-char string starting with the 2nd character followed by the 1st character

Comment: I am still learning recursion. It seems like I tried to use an iterative statement to solve the problem. I will keep trying.

Comment: The way to think about recursion is usually: Break the problem up into an easy problem and a hard problem, *and* where the hard problem is basically the original problem, but a slightly smaller version of the original problem.  Now: printing a string in reverse is hard, but printing *one character* out of a string is pretty easy.  And printing specifically the *first* character of a string is the easiest of all.

Comment: So: Think about splitting a string into its first character (easy) and the rest of the string (also easy).  Notice that you don't even need to "split" the string (that is, you don't need to construct any new strings), because you can use pointer arithmetic to get a pointer to "the rest of the string". So your solution is: Print the reverse of "the rest of the string" using a recursive call, and then, print the first character — last.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have a recursive function that outputs a string in the reverse order. Also it is a bad idea when a function depends on a global variable.

The function can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program below. Using the function you will be able to output a string in the reverse order in any stream for example in a file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE * string_reverse_output( const char *s, FILE *fp )
{
    if ( *s )
    {
        string_reverse_output( s + 1, fp );
        fputc( *s, fp );
    }
    
    return fp;
}

int main(void) 
{
    fputc( '\n', string_reverse_output( "Hello World!", stdout ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
!dlroW olleH
```

Comment: Some explanation about the ordering of lines 7 and 8 would help the OP, methinks.

Answer (score 0):

below are recursive functions to reverse a string the first is only prints and the second build the string inside `revstr` buffer and return it to caller.

```
void reverse(char *str) 
{ 
   if (*str) 
   { 
       reverse(str+1); 
       printf("%c", *str); 
   } 
} 


void recrev(char* str, char* revstr, int i)
{
   if (*str) 
   {
       recrev(str+1, revstr, i-1);
       sprintf(revstr + i, "%c", *str);    
   }
   
}


int main()
{
    
    char arr[]="hello";
    char revstr[6];
    recrev(arr, revstr, 4);
    printf("%s",revstr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Recursion is a massive overkill for this job. But still, if need be, @VladfromMoscow has given an excellent answer using recursion. Might I take the liberty to instead suggest a better solution altogether?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    printf("Enter your string: ");
    char str[100];
    scanf("%[^\n]s",str);
    str = strrev(str);
    printf("%s",str);
    return 0;
}
```

For more information on how `strrev` works, I suggest you take a look at [`strrev()` function in C](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/strrev-function-in-c/)

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse();

int main()

{

    printf("Enter String : ");

    reverse();
    return 0;
}

void reverse()

{

    char c;

    scanf("%c", &c);

    if (c != '\n')
    {
        reverse();
        printf("%c", c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your question. Moreover this is not the expected behaviour

Comment: Aside from the broken formatting (which I can't fix, as the edit queue is full) to make a good SO answer, you need to *explain* the what, and especially the *why*

Comment: @BierDav Check again. I have changed the code formatting.

Comment: @Andrew Check again. I have changed the code formatting.

If you do not understand, I will explain again.

Comment: Formatting now OK... the point of the answer is to EXPLAIN what the solution is, not just to give it... I understand it, but I am not the person asking the question, or a future searcher.